# Was there ever a version of SO that considered using grades (A, B, C, D, or F) instead of votes?

Tags: discussion, voting

This is just a discussion, not a request for change.

I am curious if a grading system has/had ever been considered.

## Pros:

- Most if not all people are familiar with at least some form of grading.
- Instead of a simple vote it does give a chance to give a more meaningful and weighted response.
- If a count of each grade was kept, then a person could learn more information based on that.
- Could this be counted as more welcoming? I don't think so but - you be the judge.

## Cons:

- Most people are probably sick of grades by now. Who wants a reminder of high school or university?
- It is more work. Instead of simply voting up or down, I now have to put more thought into my feedback. Who wants to do that?
- I'm sure there are many more. I'll add them if some come in.

Personally I am on the fence. I don't know if I would want to put more work into my feedback.

-- update --

With the help of comments and an answer I now have a clearer picture of how many different types of grading systems are out there. The idea of a letter grading system cannot easily or feasibly be implemented.

So I am off the fence.  This should never be implemented.

Comment: We'll end up at `Z` with posts, there are some below `-26` score tho. How should that be expressed. Are you thinking about an algo that maps up-/downvotes to a _grade_? What should be the weights used for rating?

Comment: Just to be clear: this grading system should *hypothetical* have replaced the current score based voting, right? It has btw always been this way, since that start in 2008.

Comment: I recall I saw a comment somewhere from Tim Post about an *alternative* ranking system for Meta posts. I don't know if it was similar to this one but I have to assume several gammification options have been on the table in the past.

Comment: @pnuts If you want to ping me remove the blank please. And I've grasped and mentioned that in my comment.

Comment: Meh, it already exists.  A=answered, B=bumped helpful, C=cold shoulder, D=downvoted, F=failed and closed.  To which many will say "I was thinking of something else".  Which is the problem.

Comment: A grading scheme with letters will be hard to communicate in an international environment. For some countries E means Excellent while for other E means terrible. A lot of countries don't use letter based grades at all.

Comment: @BDL an excellent point. Explains why.

Comment: @BDL however, i suppose part of translation and localization could take care of that.

Comment: You could have numbers? (e.g. +2, +1, 0, -1, -2)

Comment: How about: (O)utstanding, (E)xceeds Expectations, (A)cceptable, (P)oor, (D)readful, (T)roll? ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Too complicated to remember, _"OEAPDT"_ just give it a better mnemonic / acronym.

Comment: I thought it was worth it for the (D)readful and (T)roll alone...

Comment: It's the grades from the O.W.L. exams from Harry Potter. I always thought those were funny

Comment: How about SAGOBT: (S)keet, (A)wesome, (G)ood, (O)k, (B)ad, (T)rash?

Comment: @RobertColumbia if the top grade is named after our top answerer, maybe the lowest grade should be the first letter of our legendarily worst answerer? Not sure how to figure out who that is, though...

Comment: Proposing something while being on the fence about it? `F-`

Comment: @brasofilo Adding a comment without reading the first line. `F-`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Most if not all people are familiar with at least some form of
>   grading.

Grading systems differ throughout the world. In some places, it's A-F (with F being the worst), in some places, it's 1-6 (with 1 being the worst), in some places it's 1-6 (with 6 being the worst) and in some places, it's 1.0-4.0 with 4.0 being the best. Point is, grading systems aren't universal or universally understood, while a simple score system is at least universally intuitive (Positive score yay, negative score nay).

It was mentioned in a comment that this could be solved with location specific localisation of the site. Stack exchange currently only features this on a community wide level (e.g completly foreign language communities like jap.SO). The devs would have to come up with a whole localisation scheme (presumably based on IP for anonymous visitors?) and spend time curating that scheme, all to exchange an arguably more intuitive system (standard number based scoring) with a less intuitive one (school grading, which is often also percentage based in some way i.E A <91%, associating question quality with a percentage scale doesn't work well in this format).

> Instead of a simple vote it does give a chance to give a more
>   meaningful and weighted response.

This is the "score of 1-10" problem. People gravitate towards extremes or weigh their scoring to influence the overall score. You ever check metacritic? The overwhelming amount of user scores are either 1s or 10s, at which point you've arrived at our traditional up/downvote system, only with averages instead of totals.

> If a count of each grade was kept, then a person could learn more
>   information based on that.

What, specifically, would "2 people rated this as A and 1 as D" tell me? It'd be as arbitrary as voting is right now, even alot more: What grade constitutes good vs bad will be different based on the voter's opinions.

> Could this be counted as more welcoming? I don't think so but - you be
>   the judge.

No, a grading system wouldn't fix any of the quality issues. People who feel unwelcomed by votes won't feel anymore welcome if their question gets a D- average instead of just -5 score.

Comment: For your first point, are you familiar with localization? As for your point about extremes and value. There are examples out there where people do grade with some thought. If you are going to let extremes rule your decisions in this context then there isn't much I can say.

Comment: @D-Klotz Localisation is usually done between languages. Even between different english speaking countries there are differences in grading standards.

Comment: That is a oversimplification. Please review https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n

Comment: @D-Klotz As far as I know SE has not done any localisation to the site aside from other language based communities (i.E jap.so). So you propose to invent and implement a whole new country based localisation scheme just to replace the already existing and about as universally intuitive as can get scoring system with one that's more locally appropriate?

Comment: Actually I'm not proposing anything. Read the first line of the body text and the tags. I was interested in discussion. As for all of that "extra" work. It is just work. Whether it could be solved and implemented correctly 'should' be the real question.

Comment: The point doesn't change then. I'll add a paragraph about how localisation would be possible, but it seems like an undue burden on the devs for something like this.

Comment: undue burden should not be the defining criteria for whether something is done. Perhaps you meant to question whether it can be efficiently and accurately implemented. In addition the rewards/benefits versus cost aspect.

Comment: @D-Klotz Implementation cost (what I meant in that instance) is only one of my arguments against this system here. But it's certainly a valid argument in the context of SE. The devs are strapped for time, and have to prioritize their tasks. So even if this was somehow a good idea (it isn't), then it would have to pass the additional test of "Is it worth doing?" which is a pretty high bar on here.

Comment: I just read your edit on the first point. I think you are over thinking this. If I was implementing this, it would be configuration selection in the title bar. Even anonymous users could pick the grading system. Again I'm not 100% sold on this, I'm just discussing ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176655/discussion-between-magisch-and-d-klotz).