# What is the intended purpose of (public) up and down-votes on questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Can someone explain in plain words why do we really need **publicly visible** votes on questions?

According to [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), voting

> signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite

So far so good. However, votes on questions and answer don't seem have the same long term value:

- Votes on answers are fundamental feature of the site, allowing future users to distinguish between good and bad content (for some evaluation model).

  Additionally to provide short term feedback to the answerer.
- Votes on questions seem to have primarily meta value. This includes identification of problematic content (including posts that violate site rules, are off-topic, or simply require further editing) and prioritizing it in the review queues.

  They seem to have little value for the future users (question that it doesn't show research effort can still result in the quality answers, and question as such is usually of lesser importance) and to the asker (unlike close votes which eventually provide some feedback, votes are usually far to vague to be useful - it is not easy to act on "lack of research" or "unclear or not useful").

If the meta role of the question votes is their primary application, there should be no need for publicly visible score. It is completely irrelevant to queuing algorithms, and for the human reviewers, a simple visual indicator (color scale, warning sign), should be more than sufficient.

This of course might require detaching votes on question from the reputation system. Action like this would partial disfranchise aksers in favor of answerers as a (undesired?) side-effect.

On the plus side it could significantly reduce perceived hostility, especially if combined with [a civil set of canned comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371410/8371915).

Comment: visual indicator or a Grade system: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371448/was-there-ever-a-version-of-so-that-considered-using-grades-a-b-c-d-or-f-i ?

Comment: Transparency is good. Hiding it behind a vague color scheme would make it impossible to see just how "useful" a post really is.

Comment: It seems that you don't really ask about the role of up and down vote. Your question starts with that, but you then argue that they actually have no use and propose a different way of acting. Is this a question about the votes or a feature request?

Comment: Answerers like quality indicators too.

Comment: @KevinB Isn't that we have close votes? Ideally if answer is useful it should be closed and, if not improved, deleted. What voting adds on top of that?

Comment: No, usefulness is completely irrelevant when it comes to question closure. (answers can't be closed)

Comment: @user8371915 You state exactly why in your question.  Why are you asking the question that *you have already given the answer to*?

Comment: see also: [Do we really need reputation and upvotes/downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340176/839601)

Comment: Instead of voting the question down to the hell, maybe you could have answered it or close it as dupe. ("SO is not welcoming")

Comment: "Reduce perceived hostility" is good, but *voting has nothing to do with it*.

Comment: @user202729 I beg to differ. The message we allegedly try to send ("we on post, not people") is clearly not the one that many (especially first time) users receive.

Comment: @user8371915 Everything can be taken as offending to somebody. We are **not** going to reduce the amount of downvote. (this is my opinion, not the company's)

Answer (score 16):

> Votes on questions seem to have primarily meta value. This includes identification of problematic content (including posts that violate site rules, are off-topic, or simply require further editing) and prioritizing it in the review queues.

No, the votes are there to:

> signal to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite

Close votes are there to indicate that something is off topic, or is otherwise unanswerable.  Votes are there to indicate that it's an interesting, well researched, and useful question.  That's something that people are likely to be interested in knowing when deciding if they want to look at a question.

If you aren't personally interested in using that signal, you're free to not consider it.  Others find the information very helpful.

Comment: _"Close votes are there to indicate that something is off topic, or is otherwise unanswerable"_ Which often coincides with a righteously given downvote.